# About first-,second- and third-class value

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

**First-class** value can be

1. passed as an argument
2. returned from a subroutine
3. assigned into a variable.

**Second-class** value just can be passed as an argument.

**Third-class** value even can't be passed as an argument.

Why should these things defined like that? As I understand, "can be passed as an argument" means it can be pushed into the runtime stack;"can be assigned into a variable" means it can be moved into a different location of the memory; "can be returned from a subroutine" almost has the same meaning of "can be assigned into a variable" since the returned value always be put into a known address, so first class value is totally "movable" or "dynamic",second class value is half "movable" , and third class value is just "static", such as labels in C/C++ which just can be addressed by goto statement, and you can't do nothing with that address except "goto" .Does My understanding make any sense? or what do these three kinds of values mean exactly?

Comment: Can you provide the link or reference to these definitions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_object
or
Programming Language Pragmatics, Second Edition
3.5.2 First- and Second-Class Subroutines

Comment: Don't get hung up on implementation details when trying to deal with general definitions like this. For example, arguments are not necessarily passed on the stack.

Comment: These things are defined in Christopher Strachey's 1961 definition of the ALGOL language.

Answer (score 60):

Oh no, I may have to go edit Wikipedia again.

There are really only two distinctions worth making: **first-class** and not first-class.  If Michael Scott talks about a *third*-class *anything*, I'll be very depressed.

Ok, so what is "first-class," anyway?  Well, it is a term that **barely has a technical meaning**.  The meaning, when present, is usually comparative, and it applies to a *thing* in a language (I'm being deliberately vague here) that has more privileges than a comparable thing.  That's all people mean by it.

Let's look at some examples:

- Function pointers in C are first-class values because they can be passed to functions, returned from functions, and stored in heap-allocated data structures just like any other value.  Functions in Pascal and Ada are not first-class values because although they can be passed as arguments, they cannot be returned as results or stored in heap-allocated data structures.
- Struct types are second-class types in C, because there are no literal expressions of struct type.  (Since C99 there are literal *initializers* with named fields, but this is still not as general as having a literal anywhere you can use an expression.)
- Polymorphic values are second-class values in ML because although they can be let-bound to names, they cannot be lambda-bound.  Therefore they cannot be passed as arguments.  But in Haskell, because Haskell supports higher-rank polymorphism, polymorphic values are first-class.  (They can even be stored in data structures!)
- In Java, the type `int` is second class because you can't inherit from it.  Type `Integer` is first class.
- In C, labels are second class, because they don't have values and you can't compute with them.  In FORTRAN, line numbers have values and so are first class.  There is a GNU extension to C that allows you to define first-class labels, and it is jolly useful.  What does first-class mean in this case?  It means the labels have values, can be stored in data structures, and can be used in `goto`.  But those values are second class in another sense, because a label from one procedure can't meaningfully be used in a `goto` that belongs to another procedure.

Are we getting an idea how useless this terminology is?

I hope these examples convince you that the idea of "first-class" is not a very useful idea in thinking about programming languages overall.  When you're talking about a particular feature of a particular language or language family, it can be a useful shorthand ("a language isn't functional unless it has first-class, *nested* functions") but by and large you're better off saying just what you mean instead of talking about "first-class" or "not first-class" things.

As for "third class", just say no.

Comment: +1, mainly for "a thing ... that has more privileges than a comparable thing." This is the crux of it. The concrete definition is whatever the speaker intends it to be.

Comment: This is, of course, completely incorrect.  First class is actually very well defined.  The term was defined by Christopher Strachey in 1961, and has a very simple, straightforward meaning: something is first class if it supports all the operatings available to values in the language.  So, Javascript has first class functions, because anything you can do with a string you can do with a function.  C++ does not, because you cannot (for example) return a function as a result value.

Comment: GHC/Haskell does support higher-rank polymorphism, given a sufficient number of type annotations. But it does NOT support impredicative polymorphism. So something like `(forall a. a -> a, forall b. b -> b)` is not a valid type, before you say `{-# ImpredicativeTypes #-}`, that extension is extremely deprecated and does not work for any reasonable definition of work.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland I can't find your reference from 1961.  In 1967, Strachey talks about first-class functions in his *Fundamental Concepts in Programming Languages* (reprinted in *Higher-Order and Symbolic Computing* in 2000).  He writes, "In a sense procedures in Algol are second class citizens."  His statement is clearly intended to be informal and not precise.

I stand by my claims.

Answer (score 5):

Something is first-class if it is *explicitly* manipulable in the code. In other words, something is first-class if it can be programmatically manipulated at run-time.

This closely relates to meta-programming in the sense that what you describe in the code (at development time) is one meta-level, and what exists at run-time is another meta-level. But the barrier between these two meta-levels can be blurred, for instance with reflection. When something is *reified* at run-time, it becomes explicitly manipulable.

- We speak of first-class *object*, because objects can be manipulated programmatically at run-time (that's the very purpose).
- In java, you have *classes*, but they are not first-class, because the code can normally not manipulate a class unless you use reflection. But in Smalltalk, classes are first-class: the code can manipulate a class like an regular object.
- In java, you have *packages (modules)*, but they are not first-class, because the code does not manipulate package at run-time. But in NewSpeak, packages (modules) are first-class, you can instantiate a module and pass it to another module to specify the modularity at run-time.
- In C#, you have closures which are first-class functions. They exist and can be manipulated at run-time programmatically. Such things does not exists (yet) in java.

To me, the boundary first-class/not first-class is not exactly strict. It is sometimes hard to pronounce for some language constructs, e.g. java primitive types. We could say it's not first-class because it's not an object and is not manipulable through a reference that can be passed along, but the primitive value does still exists and can be manipulated at run-time.

*PS: I agree with Norman Ramsey and 2nd-class and 3rd-class value make no sense to me.*

Comment: _In C#, you have closures which are first-class functions._ I think you mean _C# has [delegates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegate_(CLI)) which allow treating functions as first-class citizens._ [(Lexical) closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) does exist in C#, but is related to C#'s support of lambda expressions and not to delegates.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they make sense to you; they're well defined and have been for 55 years.

They're actually very simple.  If you can do to it what you can do to simple values, it's first class.  Thus functions are first class in Javascript, but not in C++.

Third class things are things that are placeholders and lost in compilation, such as the labels of GOTO statements.

Everything else is second class.

This is a useful concept.  Stop pretending it doesn't exist merely because you aren't familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

1. First-class: A first-class construct is one which is an intrinsic element of a language. The following properties must hold.

   - It must form part of the lexical syntax of the language
   - It may have operators applied to it
   - It must be referenceable (for example stored in a variable)
2. Second-class: A second-class construct is one which is an intrinsic element of the language with the following properties.

   - It must form part of the lexical syntax of the language
   - It may have operators applied to it
3. Third-class: A third-class construct is one which forms part of the syntax of a language.

*in* 
Roger Keays and Andry Rakotonirainy. Context-oriented programming. In Pro- ceedings of the 3rd ACM International Workshop on Data Engineering for Wire- less and Mobile Access, MobiDe ’03, pages 9–16, New York, NY, USA, 2003. ACM.

Answer (score 0):

Those terms are very broad and not really globally well defined, but here are the most logical definitions for them:

First-class values are the ones that have actual, tangible values, and so can be operated on and go around, as variables, arguments, return values or whatever.

This doesn't really need a thorough example, does it? In C, an int is first-class.

Second-class values are more limited. They have values, but they can't be used directly, so the compiler deliberately limits what you can do with it. You can reference them, so you can still have a first-class value representing them.

For example, in C, a function is a second-class value. It can't be altered, but it can be called and referenced.

Third-class values are even more limited. They not only don't have values, but interaction is completely absent, and often it only exists to be used as compile-time attributes.

For example, in Rust, a lifetime is a third-class value. You can't use the lifetime at all. You can *only* receive it as a template parameter, you can *only* use it as a template parameter (*only* when creating a new variable), and that's *all* you can do with it.

Another example, in C++, a struct or a class is a third-class value. This doesn't need much explanation.