# What privileges do functions have over second-class things in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I read another question on stackoverflow [About first-,second- and third-class value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578872/about-first-second-and-third-class-value/2582804#2582804) saying that something that is first-class means it has more privileges than second-class things. Since functions are first-class, what privileges do they have over other things in Haskell?
I am not sure why I was marked down.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by privileges?  Functions _are_ a primitive type in Haskell, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I read another question on stackoverflow saying that something that is first-class means it has more privileges than second-class things.  Since functions are first-class, what privileges do they have over other things in Haskell?

Comment: Can I know why I was marked down?  It would help in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not that base types are second-class in Haskell (although true *primitive* types are, but that's another story), but that functions are second-class in many other languages.  An example of something second-class in Haskell is the record modification syntax: you can't pass `{ foo = bar }` to a function or return it from one.

Comment: Could you link to that other StackOverflow question? It's pretty much nonsense. Nothing in Haskell really has any such thing as "privileges"; you just compose values and possibly actions (which may certainly access resources in a way that requires system etc. privileges, but that's another issue).

Comment: leftaroundabout:  The link is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578872/about-first-second-and-third-class-value/2582804#2582804

Comment: @Fixnum and that particular second class thing is made first class with lenses. `{ foo = bar }` simply turns into `foo .~ bar` which is a value that can be passed to a function and returned from one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)

> In programming language design, a first-class citizen (also object, entity, or value) in a given programming language is an entity which supports all the operations generally available to other entities. These operations typically include being passed as a parameter, returned from a function, and assigned to a variable.

This means that in Haskell, functions can be passed as parameters, returned as values, and assigned to variables.  The language has built-in mechanics for handling, manipulating, and working with functions in general, such as the compose function `(.)`, the function `map`, and more.

A second class construct in Haskell is record syntax, as Fixnum has pointed out.  You can't construct an anonymous record and pass it into a function, it has to be an instance of a particular data type.